# Running the PyQt code does not open a window

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I am currently doing an online course in python and this exercise is focusing on PyQt. I am using Python 3.7 and Qt5.

The instructors code is exactly like mine but my code won't open a window

The main.py looks like this

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtQuick import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my main.qml is

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    height: 160
    width: 300
    visible: true
    title: MyWindow

    Item {
        id: Page
        visible: true
        width = parent.width

        Rectangle {
            height: {
                console.log("I am a comment")
                return 160
            }

            color: "#ff0000"

            Text{
                id: mainText
                text: "I am some regular text"
                height: 50
                width: parent.width
                font.pixelSize: 12
                }

            Button{
                id: mainButton
                text: "Push Me"
                anchors.top: mainText.bottom
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that when you have problems then run your code from the console/CMD, for example when executing your code for the first time I got the following message:

```
file:///xxx/main.qml:16:15: Expected token `:'
```

and the error is clear, you have to use `:` instead of `=` when setting the value of the property.

If it runs again then you get the following error message:

```
file:///xxx/main.qml:14:13: IDs cannot start with an uppercase letter
```

And the message is very clear: "Page" cannot be the name of an id since it begins with a capital letter, so the solution is to use "page".

If it runs again then you get the following error message:

```
file:///xxx/main.qml:11: ReferenceError: MyWindow is not defined
```

Clearly that variable is not defined by what you should use a string or remove that assignment.

Another improvement to your code is to build an absolute route using the location information of the .py.

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

**main.py**

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "main.qml")
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    height: 160
    width: 300
    visible: true
    title: "MyWindow"

    Item {
        id: page
        visible: true
        width: parent.width

        Rectangle {
            height: {
                console.log("I am a comment")
                return 160
            }

            color: "#ff0000"

            Text{
                id: mainText
                text: "I am some regular text"
                height: 50
                width: parent.width
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }

            Button{
                id: mainButton
                text: "Push Me"
                anchors.top: mainText.bottom
            }
        }
    }
}
```